# Splitting a numerical string in Perl

Tags: string, perl, split

I have a numerical string:

```
"13245988"
```

I want to split before and after consecutive numbers.

Expected output is:

```
1
32
45
988
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a="132459";
my @b=split("",$a);
my $k=0;
my @c=();
for(my $i=0; $i<=@b; $i++) {
    my $j=$b[$i]+1;
    if($b[$i] == $j) {
        $c[$k].=$b[$i];
    } else {
        $k++;
        $c[$k]=$b[$i];
        $k++;
    }
}
foreach my $z (@c) {
    print "$z\n";
}
```

Comment: *consecutive numbers*?

Comment: I guess that "pairs of consecutive integer digits" is what is meant, like `3 2` and `4 5` (but not `1 3`). But then why didn't you split after `98`? Oh, and *what have you tried??*

Comment: Jean, Your guess is correctly. I tried the below code. But I get output differently.
use strict; use warnings;

my $a="132459";
my @b=split("",$a); my $k=0; my @c=();

for(my $i=0;$i<=@b;$i++){
 my $j=$b[$i]+1;
 if($b[$i] == $j)
 {
  $c[$k].=$b[$i]; 
 }
 else
 {
  $k++;
  $c[$k]=$b[$i];
  $k++;
 } 
}

foreach my $z(@c){
 print "$z\n";
}

Comment: Jean, Sorry for the mistake in the expected output. The expected output is 1 32 45 988.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing based on clarified question. Something like this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "13245988";
my @b = split("",$a);

my @c = ();
push @c, shift @b; # Put first number into result.

for my $num (@b) { # Loop through remaining numbers.

    my $last = $c[$#c] % 10; # Get the last digit of the last entry.

    if(( $num <= $last+1) && ($num >= $last-1)) {
        # This number is within 1 of the last one
        $c[$#c] .= $num; # Append this one to it
    } else {
        push @c, $num; # Non-consecutive, add a new entry;
    }
}

foreach my $z (@c) {
    print "$z\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
32
45
988
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @dgw I've edited based on the clarified question, hopefully now it does.

Comment: Hi Rob, The code works fine. I did not understand this part of code "my $last = $c[$#c] % 10;". Can you elaborate this? Hope you don't mind. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Iam, `%` is the modulo operator: `my $c = $a % $b;` will divide `$a` by `$b` and assign the remainder to `$c`. You can find more detail in `man perlop`.